# How to Identify Buttons

Tags: android

i am developing a Picture Puzzle in android, i have 9 buttons each having its own image except one which is white, now what exactly i want is that when i click any button that is Side by side with the white button or below or above the white white button, the attributes of both the button swaps, i mean the white button changes into the clicked button and the clicked button changes into the white one and also their ids. i am doing this but seems illogical and also not working.

```
private OnClickListener btnClick = new OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View Sender) {

        ImageButton Incoming=(ImageButton) Sender;
        try{    

                ImageButton temp=MyButtons[Incoming.getId()];
                MyButtons[Incoming.getId()].setImageDrawable(MyButtons[Incoming.getId()-1].getDrawable());
                MyButtons[Incoming.getId()].setId(MyButtons[Incoming.getId()-1].getId());
                MyButtons[Incoming.getId()-1].setImageDrawable(temp.getDrawable());
                MyButtons[Incoming.getId()-1].setId(temp.getId());



        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }
};
```

Comment: What happens? They both end up looking the same with the same id?

Comment: this code is wiered, i mean the ids are not the way this code is, it was a try just, the ids and images of other buttons change

Answer (score 0):

The code you have is similar to this:

```
Button temp = MyButtons[1];
MyButtons[1].id = MyButtons[0].id;
MyButtons[0].id = temp.id; // FAIL - same as MyButtons[0].id = MyButtons[1].id
```

You are assuming that the first line is making a COPY of the button when it is only holding a reference to the existing button. You then set the id of the button:

```
MyButtons[Incoming.get()].setId(MyButtons[Incoming.getId()-1].getId());
```

and then try to set the id of the other button:

```
MyButtons[Incoming.get()-1].setId(temp.getId()));
```

which is exactly the same as:

```
MyButtons[Incoming.get()-1].setId(MyButtons[Incoming.getId()].getId());
```

You need to save the id and image, not the button reference.

Comment: but the buttons are randomly distributed, the ids are not in a sequence

Comment: this thing that you said is good but for when the buttons are in sequence, i want to i dentify buttons adjacent to the clicked button